# Input string was not in a correct format. When i try to convert char->string->int

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code inside my asp.net vmc web application :-

```
var getNumbers = (from t in ut.newTag
                                where char.IsDigit(t)
                                select t).ToString();
            tech.PartialTag = Convert.ToInt32(getNumbers);
```

but i am getting the following exception :-

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

so can anyone advice how i can solve this issue??

Comment: what's your input then?

Comment: What is the value of getNumbers ?

Comment: it refer to the getNumbers

Comment: Two steps: First, what is ut? Next, what does getNumbers get set to?

Comment: @n8wrl ut.NewTag is a string

Comment: Is the intent to translate input such as "10someNonDigits00" to 1000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a ctor of String taking a `char[]` as  parameter, so

```
var getNumbers = new String((from t in ut.newTag
                                where char.IsDigit(t)
                                select t).ToArray());
tech.PartialTag = Convert.ToInt32(getNumbers);
```

*Difference with Sergey's answer* :

if your input is `1A2` for example, Sergey's solution won't accept the input.

But my solution (based on yours) will take 12.

So, it depends on what you need (I think Sergey's one is clearer, it just rejects non integers inputs).

Comment: You can simplify string creation a little with `new String(ut.newTag.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray())` :)

Comment: Yup, I know the fluent syntax, was just trying to be as closed as OP's try ;)

Answer (score 5):

`getNumbers` is a string, containing type name of string enumerator It will look like

```
"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`1[System.String,System.String]"
```

You obviously can't convert that type name to integer. If you want to try parse `newTag` and assign it to `PartialTag` if there is an integer:

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse(ut.newTag, out value))
    tech.PartialTag = value;
```

Comment: +1: Unless OP wants to ignore non-digits altogether `TryParse` is much more readable alternative to strange LINQ expression (even Regular expression would be more readable and expected in validation code).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks :) Just want to add, that regex solution you mentioned will look like `string getNumbers = Regex.Replace(ut.newTag, @"\D", ""));`

Comment: Are you not lazy anymore? ;) Or still lazy but covertly.

Comment: @Silvermind ah, that would take so many efforts to explain.. :)